# Form instance different inside `fixture.componentInstance` and `this` inside component method

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, angular-forms

I am trying to test a component method in Angular. It uses a reactive form.

The test is as follows.

```
fit('should try to login with credentials when the form is valid', () => {
  const form = fixture.componentInstance.signupForm;
  fixture.componentInstance.ngOnInit();
  const email = 'test@joveo.com',
    password = 'test',
    rememberMe = false,
    redirect = '';

  form.controls['email'].setValue(email);
  form.controls['password'].setValue(password);
  form.controls['rememberMe'].setValue(rememberMe);
  expect(form.valid).toBe(true);
  const action = new AuthActions.Login({
    email,
    password,
    rememberMe,
    redirect
  });
  console.log(form, form.valid, form.value);
  fixture.componentInstance.login();
  expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(action);
});
```

The Component method `login` is defined as follows.

```
login() {
    console.log(this.signupForm, this.signupForm.valid, this.signupForm.value);
    if (!this.signupForm.valid) {
      return;
    }
    const { email, password, rememberMe } = this.signupForm.value;
    const redirect = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['redirect'] || '';
    this.store.dispatch(new Login({ email, password, rememberMe, redirect }));
  }
```

As visible, I have a `console.log` statement in the test and in the method as well.

Since the `fixture.componentInstance` called the login method inside the test, I would expect `this` to be that componentInstance and so should be the `signupForm`.

But they show different results. Inside the method, the values are null for form controls.

Am I doing something really silly here?

### **Update**

I took a wild guess that when I set the values using something like `form.controls['email'].setValue('test@test.joveo.com')` it isn't really changing the actual `fixture.componentInstance.signupForm`.

So after all my `setValue` calls, I reassigned the `form` to `fixture.componentInstance.signupForm` and it worked.

This is totally breaking everything I know about how JS references work!

Comment: I would recommend interacting with the component through the DOM, rather than directly in your unit test - set the `input` values and simulate a `.click()` on the login button. See e.g. [the testing guide](https://angular.io/guide/testing#use-a-page-object) for one pattern for this.

Comment: But the advantage of using a reactive form is that it allows for the testing to be done from within the component code instead of touching DOM isn't it? That's why I used `setValue` on my formControls. I also updated the post with something I did and managed to make it work but it seems hacky.

Comment: As I understand it, the advantage for testing is that you can do it in async/fakeAsync blocks and avoid timing issues. The advantage of testing from the actual interface is that you can more easily refactor the code later.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by calling `ngOnInit()` before `const form = fixture.componentInstance.signupForm;`

Since in my `ngOnInit` I was assigning `this.signupForm` to `new FormGroup({...})` the reference was changing and the `form` variable wasn't aware of it.